# Which is more efficient? (Variables for JavaScript loop)

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, performance

To keep it simple, sat at my desk wondering if there is a difference in efficiency between (in JavaScript):

```
var i = 0;

for(i=0; i<Something.length; i++) foo();

for(i=0; i<Something.length; i++) foo();
```

And...

```
for(var i=0; i<Something.length; i++) foo();

for(var i=0; i<Something.length; i++) foo();
```

Comment: And what results did you get with performance tests before giving up and posting on SO?

Comment: Use www.jperf.com to check the efficiency of your code.

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial do you mean www.jSperf.com ?

Comment: @BuhBuh Yes i meant that,Sorry I misspelled it.

Comment: Just looking at the JSperfs now. Wow! People reply quick on here. Will assess and accept an answer in abit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one will be faster, you will cache `Something.length` in variable so it will not be interpreted during loop:

```
for(var i=0, len = Something.length; i<len; i++) foo();
```

Here is a [test](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-dumb-test)

But moving var definition from loop will be really a bit faster without caching

Comment: Accepted this, because of the JSperf. Helpful, thanks. Seems the fastest is creating the variables out side of the for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried with 1000000 loops, the first runs for 2.7sec, the second runs for 2.418sec.

Apparently, the first one is faster.

But as JavaScript has no block scope, `i` in both cases will still be available out of the loop and you may have error if you forget to init it later.